# SQL Server OFFSET FETCH - best way to check whether there are more records left

Tags: sql-server, pagination

I am using SQL Server's OFFSET FETCH construct to achieve pagination. The UI client needs a way to determine whethee there are more records to be fetched. What is the standard way of achieving this? I remember having read that the results follow some kind of semantics which help the client figure out whether there are more rows, but I am not able to find that now. Can you please help me with this? If there is no such semantic, then what is the best way of achieving this? I really want to avoid having to run another query to check if there are more records.

Comment: Either count before hand to know the size of the result, or query and see if you get more rows. Those are the ways I know of.

Comment: Include `total_rows = COUNT(*) OVER()` as a column in the output. If that is greater than `current_page * page_size` then there are more rows to fetch...